# Firewall refuse my connection to DB

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2008, connection-refused

We are working on software that require to connect to database on the server (Win2012)(LAN), after activating windows firewall, we couldn't connect to DB.

I've set a rule for inbound and I Excluded our ports (default 1443 and Software port) and it doesn't work. then I set a new rule just to make sure that Excluding ports is not our problem so I excluded All the ports (Allow for all ports) and still can't connect to DB.

Only when deactivate firewall, everything works fine!! so where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: *"when deactivate firewall, everything works fine!! so where is the problem?"* - The problem is the firewall apparently. But since you don't really post HOW you configure the firewall, well, we can't tell IF & WHAT you may be doing wrong. Please [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/926141/edit) your question accordingly and add those details.

Comment: it's windows firewall and default configurations,  I just added rule to allow the connection for our ports on inbound. by the way I've edited the question.

Comment: SQL server uses by default dynamic ports for the instances. You should not exclude specific ports, you should add the exclusion by the SQL server executable. The text in the "details" box most probably contains more helpful information you cut off with your screenshot. It's plain text that can be copied and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Run [tcpview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) and watch what port you forget to put an exception on it.

Or simply remove the firewall if the server serve only LAN client, the risk is small. (as the windows firewall is a stateless firewall on most protocol. You will end up whitelisting all port on the server that is open)

Comment: thank you for reply, Actually I added rule that allow to all ports to connect but still no connection!!